# Elliptic curves over QQ with identical 13-isogeny

Tags: nt.number-theory

Dear MO Community,

this is not a real maths question, but rather the hope that someone else has stored in his or her private archive some data I am interested in.

> I'd like to know some pairs of non-isogenous elliptic curves over $\mathbf Q$ possessing the same cyclic isogeny of degree $13$, i.e. they both have an $13$-isogeny defined over $\mathbf Q$ and the kernels (over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$) of these isogenies are isomorphic as $Gal(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$-modules.

A quick and naive search on my computer was without results so far.

Maybe someone knowns some examples of such pairs of elliptic curves and is willing to share them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would look at Kraus-Oesterlé (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1166121) and and the papers which refer to it.

Comment: As indicates the title of the article mentioned by Chandan, this questions was raised by Mazur, see the article *Questions about Numbers* http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/papers/scanQuest.pdf page 44.

Comment: Looking for weight 2 newforms whose Fourier coefficient are almost always congruent modulo 13 gives the pairs (52a,988b) and (208c,3952c) (notations from Cremona's tables), but I haven't checked whether this yields elliptic curves with isomorphic Galois modules.

Comment: But these elliptic curves seem to have irreducible mod 13 representations.

Comment: Dear Chandan, thanks for the reference. Dear François, thanks for giving it a try. Unfortunately, I encountered the same problem. All pairs of elliptic curves with isomorphic mod 13 representation I know of have irreducible representations. I checked all possibilities of conductor up to 10,000. There are exactly five such pairs: (52a1, 988b1), (208c1, 3952c1), (468c1, 8892j1), (735c1, 9555h1), and (735d1, 9555n1).

Comment: Of course, I meant that there are five pairs of isogeny classes (52a, 988b), (208c, 3952c), (468c, 8892j), (735c, 9555h), and (735d, 9555n). The second and third, as well as the fourth and fifth are quadratic twists of each other.

Comment: What a nice question!  I would start like this:  you are looking for points on the modular surface S parametrizing pairs (E,E',C,C',phi), where E and E' are elliptic curves, C and C' are cyclic 13-subgroups, and phi is an isomorphism between C and C'.  S is a quotient of X_1(13) x X_1(13) by the diagonal in the (Z/13Z)^* x (Z/13Z)^* action.  Is S general type, rational, what?  One could work this out and get ideas. 

Comment: Dear Jordan, thank you very much for your comment. Shouldn't S be the quotient of X_0(13 x X_0(13) by the diagonal in the (Z/13Z)^* x (Z/13Z)^* action?

Comment: No it really should be  X_1(13) x X_1(13) modulo the diagonal in  (Z/13Z)^* x (Z/13Z)^* . To see this X_1(13) x X_1(13) classifies pairs (E,E',P,P') where P and P' are points of order 13. Now this data gives in a canonical way an isomorphism phi between the groups E=<P> and E'=<P'> by sending P to P'. To remember the isomorphism but forget the generators P,P' on has to quotient out by the diagonal (Z/13Z)^* x (Z/13Z)^* . Note that (Z/13Z)^* x (Z/13Z)^* doesn't even act on  X_0(13) x X_0(13) .

Comment: Dear Maarten, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: An example is given in [this Darmon's paper](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/02.Serre-conjecture/paper.pdf), in §3.1.1, Ex. 5. The curves are 998B, 52A in Cremona's tables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**Edited** *mostly to include the second example, corresponding to*
$(t,X) = (3,-115/126)$]

Thanks to Jordan Ellenberg for

[calling attention to this nice question on his blog](http://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/elliptic-curves-with-isomorphic-cyclic-13-subgroups).
I didn't remember an example in my "private archive", but the question
is close enough to some of my previous computations that I was able to
adapt those techniques here.  It turns out that there are infinitely many
such pairs (even up to quadratic twist); one example has both torsion
subgroups defined over the 7th cyclotomic field ${\bf Q}(\zeta_7)$:
the curve with coefficients $[0,-1,1,-2,-1]$, i.e.
$y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 1$,
of conductor $147 = 3 \cdot 7^2$ and discriminant $-147$,
and the curve with coefficients
$$
[0,-1,1,-1424883795842044404862,-20702237422068075268318817670099],
$$
conductor $8480886141 = 3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 251 \cdot 17681$,
and discriminant $3 \cdot 7^2 13^{13} 251^{13} 17681$.
This felt familiar, and it turns out that I had already encountered
the quadratic twists of these curves by ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-7})$
because one of them, also of conductor $3 \cdot 7^2$ but
discriminant $-3 \cdot 7^8$, is the Jacobian of the Shimura
modular curve computed in my paper

> Elkies, N.D.: Shimura Curves for Level-3 Subgroups of the $(2,3,7)$
>   Triangle Group, and Some Other Examples,
>   *Lecture Notes in Computer Science* **4076**
>   (proceedings of ANTS-7, 2006; F.Hess, S.Pauli, and M.Pohst, ed.),
>   302$-$316;
>   [arXiv:math/0409020](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409020v2.pdf).

(so it was already in my "public archive"...).  See page 11 of
[the arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409020v2.pdf):
Mark Watkins noted that this curve 147-B1(I) actually has 13-torsion
over the cubic field ${\bf Q}(\zeta_7^{\phantom1} + \zeta_7^{-1})$;
I then explained this observation from the Shimura-curve structure,
and noted (footnote 5) that the twist of $X_1(13)$ parametrizing
curves over ${\bf Q}$ with a $13$-torsion point over
${\bf Q}(\zeta_7^{\phantom1} + \zeta_7^{-1})$
has at least one more orbit of rational points, which yields
the curve of conductor $8480886141$.

As Jordan observes in his blog, and also in his comment here,
the question of finding pairs of curves with "the same" cyclic
$13$-isogeny is equivalent to finding rational points
(away from some degeneracy locus) on a certain surface $S$.
This surface turns out to be "honestly elliptic" of the simplest kind
(with $\chi=3$): the canonical class $K_S$ is positive but not ample,
with a two-dimensional space of sections that gives a map
$S \rightarrow {\bf P}^1$ whose fibers are curves of genus $1$.
This fibration has sections defined over ${\bf Q(i)}$ but not over ${\bf Q}$.
But many of the first few fibers have rational points small enough
to find by a brief computer search.  Any one such point yields
infinitely many rational points on its fiber, and thus infinitely
many pairs of $j$-invariants of elliptic curves with Galois-isomorphic
subgroups of order $13$.

The surface has a birational model
$
Y^2 = (X^2+4) A(X),
$
where $A(X)$ is the quadratic $A_2 X^2 + A_1 X + A_0$
whose coefficients $A_2,A_1,A_0$ are the following sextics in $t$:
$$
A_2(t) = t^6-4t^5+6t^4-2t^3+t^2-2t+1,
$$ $$
A_1(t) = -6t^5+26t^4-22t^3-4t^2+6t,
$$ $$
A_0(t) = 4t^6-8t^5+37t^4-74t^3+57t^2-16t+4.
$$
Thus we have for each $t$ a curve of genus $1$, though without
an obvious rational point (except for the degenerate $t=0,1,\infty$
where every $X$ makes $(X^2+4) (A_2(t) X^2 + A_1(t) X + A_0)$ a square
but the resulting elliptic curves $E,E'$ are isomorphic).
So I tried a few small values of $t$ with
Stahlke and Stoll's program **ratpoints**.
For $t=2$ the program reported an obstruction, and indeed
there's no $11$-adic solution.  Hence our elliptic fibration
has no section over ${\bf Q}$ (else we could specialize it at $t=2$),
though there are certainly sections over ${\bf Q}(i)$, namely $X=\pm 2i$
(and also the roots of $A(X)$).
Still we can look for rational points on individual fibers,
and we already succeed for $t=3$, finding a rational solution
at $X=-115/126$, and several solutions of larger height for
other small $t$.  An hour's exhaustive search up to height $50$ for $t_0$
and $500$ for $X$ finds three further solutions, including
$(t,X) = (33/17,0)$ which leads to the curves of conductor
$147$ and $8480886141$ exhibited above.  The solution
$(t,X) = (3,-115/126)$ corresponds to the curves
$$
[1, 1, 0, -2193228435814, -4048327365374399852],
$$
with conductor
$133333589432694 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 181^2 \cdot 263 \cdot 607^2$,
and
$$
[1, 1, 0, -9358273692452696799, -11018986378569871927950945915],
$$
with conductor
$N = 18612166837338258 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 79 \cdot 181^2 \cdot 607^2 \cdot 3253$
(these curves were recovered from their $j$-invariants using J.Cremona's
conductor-minimizing **Sage** routine **EllipticCurve_from_j**);
both curves have $x$-coordinates in the same cubic field of discriminant
$181^2 607^2$, and $y$-coordinates in the quadratic extension
of that field by $\sqrt{-181 \cdot 607}$.

Details of the computation of the surface etc. coming soon
(but probably in a separate answer because this is already
quite long or a **Mathoverflow** answer...).

Comment: This answer deserves to be included in "The Best of MatheOverflow".

Comment: Dear Noam, thank you very much for your awesome answer! I would love to read your upcoming notes about the computation of the surface.